# Fixing '../../' paths in python

Tags: python

Is there an easy way in Python to resolve path operators like `..`?  For instance is there a function call that will convert: `/../../test/../path` to `/path`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use [`os.path.realpath()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath) to get the canonical path.  To get a normalised relative path, use [`os.path.normpath()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath).

Comment: realpath() is generic function.  Works perfectly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `abspath` in the `os.path` module.

> os.path.abspath(path)
>
> Return a normalized absolutized
>   version of the pathname path. On most
>   platforms, this is equivalent to
>   normpath(join(os.getcwd(), path)).

Answer (score 9):

If you are using the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module, the method to use is [`resolve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve):

```
In [304]: print(p)
/group_workspaces/cems2/fiduceo/Users/gholl/logs/2016/08/10/srf_errorprop/../../../../../scratch/accidentally_deleted_shift_log

In [305]: print(p.resolve())
/group_workspaces/cems2/fiduceo/Users/gholl/scratch/accidentally_deleted_shift_log
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use the function `os.path.abspath` from `os.path`